# Most understandable notes on Jacquet-Langlands?

Tags: automorphic-forms, nt.number-theory

I am particularly interested in the comparison of the trace formula part of Jacquet-Langlands. But I found the original text hard to read.

Comment: Take a look at Jacquet and Gelbart article in Corvallis. They give a very nice account of the trace formula part of Jacquet-Langlands.

Comment: A nice summary of the Jacquet-Langlands Lecture Notes, is Alain Robert 's Bourbaki seminar 
http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SB/SB_1971-1972__14_/SB_1971-1972__14__295_0/SB_1971-1972__14__295_0.pdf


Comment: How about Gelbart's book "Automorphic Forms on Adele Groups"? Especially section 10 where he explains the comparison of the trace formulas.

Answer (score 7):

I think that you may like the notes by Ioan Badulescu: see 
http://www-math.univ-poitiers.fr/~badulesc/pub/JLtata1.pdf

They are a 20 pages modern essentially complete exposition of the proof of Jacquet-Langlands not only for $Gl_2$ but for higher higher rank linear groups and their inner form as well.

Comment: @Joel: thanks for the notes. I am at the Tata Institute but I did not know about them! I looked through the notes. They treat only the local correspondence; not the global one. I believe that most of the last chapter of Jacquet-Langlands is about the $global$ correspondence. 

Of course, the "local" statement uses some global ideas, but I think these notes do not treat completely the global case. 

Answer (score 3):

I suggest Gelbart Lecture notes Arthur trace formula in addition to Gelbart Jacquet (Aakumadula`s reference).

Here is a site with references: http://www.charlesli.org/math/trace.html

Comment: The LN only treat the number field case though, where as JL consider arbitrary global fields.